# Firebase react native loading issue

Tags: firebase, react-native, loading

I'm new at react native and I try to build an mobile app. I'm using Firebase for applications. When I try to login, it stucks on the loading page. And getting this warning:

> Setting a timer for a long period of time, i.e. multiple minutes, is a performance and correctness issue on Android as it keeps the timer module awake, and timers can only be called when the app is in the foreground. See https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/12981 for more info.
> (Saw setTimeout with duration 3600000ms)

What should I do?

Also authentication code is here:

```
import { AsyncStorage } from 'react-native';

export const SIGNUP = 'SIGNUP';
export const LOGIN = 'LOGIN';
export const AUTHENTICATE = 'AUTHENTICATE';
export const LOGOUT = 'LOGOUT';

let timer;

export const authenticate = (userId, token, expiryTime) => {
  return dispatch => {
    dispatch(setLogoutTimer(expiryTime));
    dispatch({ type: AUTHENTICATE, userId: userId, token: token });
  };
};

export const signup = (email, password) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signUp?key=...',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: true
        })
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorResData = await response.json();
      const errorId = errorResData.error.message;
      let message = 'Bir terslik var!';
      if (errorId === 'EMAIL_EXISTS') {
        message = 'Bu e-posta zaten kayıtlı!';
      }
      throw new Error(message);
    }

    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData);
    dispatch(
      authenticate(
        resData.localId,
        resData.idToken,
        parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
      )
    );
    const expirationDate = new Date(
      new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
    );
    saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirationDate);
  };
};

export const login = (email, password) => {
  return async dispatch => {
    const response = await fetch(
      'https://identitytoolkit.googleapis.com/v1/accounts:signInWithPassword?key=...',
      {
        method: 'POST',
        headers: {
          'Content-Type': 'application/json'
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
          email: email,
          password: password,
          returnSecureToken: true
        })
      }
    );

    if (!response.ok) {
      const errorResData = await response.json();
      const errorId = errorResData.error.message;
      let message = 'Bir terslik var!';
      if (errorId === 'EMAIL_NOT_FOUND') {
        message = 'Böyle bir e-posta yok!';
      } else if (errorId === 'INVALID_PASSWORD') {
        message = 'Bu şifre geçersiz!';
      }
      throw new Error(message);
    }

    const resData = await response.json();
    console.log(resData);
    dispatch(
      authenticate(
        resData.localId,
        resData.idToken,
        parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
      )
    );
    const expirationDate = new Date(
      new Date().getTime() + parseInt(resData.expiresIn) * 1000
    );
    saveDataToStorage(resData.idToken, resData.localId, expirationDate);
  };
};

export const logout = () => {
  clearLogoutTimer();
  AsyncStorage.removeItem('userData');
  return { type: LOGOUT };
};

const clearLogoutTimer = () => {
  if (timer) {
    clearTimeout(timer);
  }
};

const setLogoutTimer = expirationTime => {
  return dispatch => {
    timer = setTimeout(() => {
      dispatch(logout());
    }, expirationTime);
  };
};

const saveDataToStorage = (token, userId, expirationDate) => {
  AsyncStorage.setItem(
    'userData',
    JSON.stringify({
      token: token,
      userId: userId,
      expiryDate: expirationDate.toISOString()
    })
  );
};
```

Comment: You shouldn't ignore it but this message is a warning and might not be the reason your application is stuck on the loading screen. Give us your code (And/or a minimal repro on Expo would be nice) please so we can check it.

Comment: Thank you for your interest! I edited my question, you can check it.